# "TSLint still there" => upgrading from TSlint to ESLint

Tags: angular, eslint, tslint, angular12

I'm working on angular 10 project, which was upgraded to angular 12. TSLint is no longer used in angular 12, but since that project was upgraded to angular 12, it still has `tslint.json` and its packages. How do I remove it? The project uses prettier as well.

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "academic-schedule",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "format:check": "prettier \"src/{app,environments}/**/*{.ts,.html,.json,.scss}\" --check",
    "format:write": "prettier \"src/{app,environments}/**/*{.ts,.html,.json,.scss}\" --write"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^12.1.1",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.8.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.15.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^11.4.3",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.7.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.42.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to edit this post several times, but I get an error that I can't resolve. I wanted to change the title: "TSLint still there" => upgrading from TSlint to ESLint. And add the TSLint and ESLint-tags on the bottom. It's just to increase the odds that people who have the same question stumble on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this offer a solution [Nx: Migrating Angular Applications From TSLint to ESLint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtVqJMzsqyY)?

Hope this helps !  Take care & good luck!

Comment: I just took my components, modules, etc. into the newest angular 12 solution. But yes, it does. I'm using only prettier, not sure if prettier + ESLint is a thing.